# Como fazer um foreach para um array de arrays?

Tags: php, array

Como posso fazer eu um `foreach` para um array de arrays como este:

```
array
(
    [option1] => 2
    [option2] => array
                 (
                     [name] => "ola mundo"
                     [id]   => "123456"
                     ...
                 )
    ...
)
```

O array pode variar de opções e eu quero imprimir todos os campos "name" encontrados.

*Nota: de preferência a forma mais eficaz de fazer.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O PHP tem uma função interessante que aplica uma outra função a todos os membros de uma array.

Chama-se [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Teste assim:

```
$array = array(array('nome' => 'Luis', 'id' => 1), array('nome' => 'Rui', 'id' => 2));

$nomes = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($item, $key) {
    global $nomes;
    if ($key == 'nome') $nomes[] = $item;
});

var_dump($nomes);

// resultado:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Luis"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Rui"
}
```

[Exemplo online aqui](http://ideone.com/cooV7X)

Outra ideia é fazer uma função recursiva que passa informação a si própria. O resultado é uma array multidimensional.

```
$array = array(array('nome' => 'Luis', 'id' => 1), array('nome' => 'Rui', 'id' => 2));

function recurse($array, $retorno){

    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) $interno[] = recurse($item, $retorno);
        else if ($key == 'nome') $interno[] = $item;
    }
    if (count($retorno)) $retorno = array_merge($interno, $retorno);
    else $retorno = $interno;
    return $retorno;
}

var_dump(recurse($array, array()));

// resultado:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Luis"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Rui"
  }
}
```

[Exemplo online aqui](http://ideone.com/k4EGYe)

Comment: Nunca tinha prestado muita atenção nessa função, mas é muito melhor que escrever aquelas linhas todas.

Comment: Excelente resposta Sergio +1

Comment: O exemplo desapareceu @Sergio

Comment: @JorgeB. hmmm triste. Vou colocar de volta mais logo, de um site mais credível... obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
   $ar = array
    (
        [option1] => 2
        [option2] => array
                     (
                         [name] => "ola mundo"
                         [id]   => "123456"
                         ...
                     )
        ...
    )

foreach($ar as $value)
{
   if(!is_array($value))
       continue;

   foreach($value as $v_key =>$v_value)
   {
        if($v_key=="name")
        {
           $nomes[] = $v_value;

        //se nesta array existir apenas uma chave nome para este loop e salta para o´
        //mais exterior
          continue 2;
        }


   }
}
```

Se o tiver o php 5.5.0 pode usar o array_column
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: O array-column funciona mesmo com esse array assim?

Comment: eu não experimentei porque tenho o 5.3 instalado, mas segundo a documentação funciona sim.

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira `array_column` para versões anteriores que o php 5.5 : https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Answer (score 2):

Caso seja um array somente com duas dimensões, como a saída de um banco de dados por exemplo, o `array_column` é a solução mais simples:

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['nome' => 'Luis', 'id' => 31], 
    ['nome' => 'Rui', 'id' => 42],
    ['nome' => 'Joao', 'id' => 113],
    ['nome' => 'Joaquim', 'id' => 434],
    ['nome' => 'Jorge', 'id' => 503],
];

var_dump(array_column($array, 'nome'));

// Se quiser, pode aproveitar uma segunda coluna para usar como key do novo array
var_dump(array_column($array, 'nome', 'id'));
```

[Exemplo executável](http://ideone.com/On1KXq).

Lembrando que o `array_column` é uma das novidades do php 5.5, porém essa função pode ser utilizada facilmente nas versões anteriores utilizando uma [implementação no próprio php](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).

Caso seu array tenha ainda mais dimensões, outra maneira é utilizar um [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), presente na [SPL](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl.php) do PHP.

```
<?php
    $array = [
        ['nome' => 'Luis', 'id' => 1], 
        ['nome' => 'Rui', 'id' => 2],
        ['nome' => 'Joao', 'id' => 3],
        ['nome' => 'Joaquim', 'id' => 4],
        ['nome' => 'Jorge', 'id' => 5],
    ];
    
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

    $nomes = [];
    
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value)
        if ($key == 'nome') $nomes[] = $value;
   
    
    var_dump($nomes);
```

[Exemplo Executável](http://ideone.com/UbE8iF).

<sup><sup>Ps.: Sergio, reaproveitei seu Ideone ;)</sup></sup>