# Excluir Item Array

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando remover um item de um `array` correspondente ao [NUMERO] mas não está dando certo.

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NUMERO] => 123
            [DATA] => 11/11/1111
            [VALOR] => 2,22
            [ARQUIVO] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NUMERO] => 456
            [DATA] => 12/12/1212
            [VALOR] => 33,33
            [ARQUIVO] => 
        )
)
```

Bolei essa função para retorna o KEY para então removê-lo:

```
function hasArrayKey( $array, $value ){
    foreach( $array as $key => $temp ){
        if( array_search( $value, $temp ) !== false ){
            return $key;
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

Mais ele remove o KEY "0" caso não encontre:

```
$nota = hasArrayKey( $_SESSION['NOTAS'], '999' );
if( $nota >= 0 ){
    unset( $_SESSION['NOTAS'][$nota] );
}
if( !$nota ){
    echo "Nota not found\n";
}
```

Algum ideia, pessoal?

Comment: Você deseja remover do array pelo valor ou pela key ?

Comment: Remover pelo valor correspondente ao [NUMERO]

Comment: você sabe se ele esta achando a $key correta? já tentou imprimir a $key?

Comment: Sim ele acha a KEY correta

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34790/7210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hugo, alterei sua função para receber [parâmetros como referencia](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php), assim fica mais simples para remover as linhas indesejadas.

Com base no seu comentário, achei mais seguro trocar a comparação do `array_search` por uma verificação simples da posição `NUMERO`. Pois caso o campo `VALOR` seja igual ao campo  `NUMERO`, essa linha será excluída também (Exemplo `Numero = 2543` e `Valor = 25`, case seja passado 25 para a função, essa posição será removida).

```
<?php

function removeByNumero(&$array, $numero){
    foreach($array as $key => $row){
        if($row['NUMERO'] == $numero){
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}

$array = array(
    0 => array(
            'NUMERO' => 123,
            'DATA' => '11/11/1111',
            'VALOR' => 2.22,
            'ARQUIVO' => 'XPTO'
        ),
    1 => array(
            'NUMERO' => 456,
            'DATA' => '12/12/1212',
            'VALOR' => 33.33,
            'ARQUIVO' => 'XPPT'
    ),
);

removeByNumero($array, 234);
var_dump($array);   // Não remove nada

removeByNumero($array, 123);
var_dump($array);   // Remove a key 0
```

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que se ele não encontra retorna false para a variável `$nota`.

No `if` quando você faz uma comparação matemática ele converte para `int`.

Então se `if( $nota >= 0 )` é o mesmo que `0 >= 0` e por isso ele entra no `if` e remove o elemento de chave `0`.

Considere alterar o código para ser assim:

```
function hasArrayKey( $array, $value ){
    foreach( $array as $key => $temp ){
        if( array_search($value, $temp) ){
            return $key; 
        }
    }
}

$keyToRemove = hasArrayKey( $_SESSION['NOTAS'], '123' ) ;
if( $keyToRemove >= 0 ) {
    unset( $_SESSION['NOTAS'][$keyToRemove] ); 
} else {
    echo "Nota not found\n";
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo!.. se eu for remover a `[NUMERO] => 123` ele não acha.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na segunda parte do código.

```
$nota = hasArrayKey( $_SESSION['NOTAS'], '999' );
if( $nota >= 0 ){
    unset( $_SESSION['NOTAS'][$nota] );
}
if( !$nota ){
    echo "Nota not found\n";
}
```

No trecho $nota >= 0 ele sempre retornará **TRUE**, pois o php automaticamente converte **FALSE** para  **0** e vice-versa.

Então, ele passa pelo if, afinal FALSE == 0 é **TRUE**.

Logo abaixo ele faz  unset( $_SESSION['NOTAS'][$nota] );

Novamente o $nota tem o valor **FALSE**, más o PHP irá converter para **0**.

Excluindo assim a primeira chave do array.

Você pode fazer **if($nota)** apenas, ou então **if($nota > 0)**.

Eu recomendo o **if($nota)**.

Comment: De qualquer forma não da certo veja:                            se eu for excluir a `[NUMERO] => 123`                     o KEY dela é `0` logo **if($nota)** não excluir

Comment: @Hugo. A questão toda é o if( $nota >= 0 ). Esse if SEMPRE será TRUE.
Ele SEMPRE vai entrar no sub bloco. entende?