# Exibindo vetor com foreach - PHP

Tags: php, foreach, array

Alguém teria um exemplo de um foreach para exibir os dados do vetor abaixo?

Código:

```
Array
(
  [empregadoTO] => Array
    (
        [0] => EmpregadoTO Object
            (
                [id:EmpregadoTO:private] => 1
                [nome:EmpregadoTO:private] => Raphael
                [sobrenome:EmpregadoTO:private] => Ribeiro
                [cpf:EmpregadoTO:private] => 222.222.222-22
                [dia:EmpregadoTO:private] => 07
                [mes:EmpregadoTO:private] => 08
                [ano:EmpregadoTO:private] => 1983
                [idEstadoCivil:EmpregadoTO:private] => 3
                [estadoCivil:EmpregadoTO:private] => Divorciado(a)
                [idEscolaridade:EmpregadoTO:private] => 3
                [escolaridade:EmpregadoTO:private] => Ensino Fundamental (1º Grau) Completo
                [sexo:EmpregadoTO:private] => M
                [foto:EmpregadoTO:private] => 
                [email:EmpregadoTO:private] => raphael@gmail.com
                [senha:EmpregadoTO:private] => 4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93
                [cep:EmpregadoTO:private] => 22222-222
                [idEstado:EmpregadoTO:private] => 
                [cidade:EmpregadoTO:private] => AÇAILÂNDIA
                [bairro:EmpregadoTO:private] => rrrrrrrrr
                [telefone:EmpregadoTO:private] => (22)1111-1111
                [celular:EmpregadoTO:private] => (12)22222-2222
                [newsletterNoticia:EmpregadoTO:private] => 1
                [newsletterVaga:EmpregadoTO:private] => 1
                [idStatus:EmpregadoTO:private] => 1
                [dataCadastro:EmpregadoTO:private] => 2015-01-14 14:01:40
                [estado:EmpregadoTO:private] => MA
            )

    )

[informacaoInteresseTO] => InformacaoInteresseTO Object
    (
        [id:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 1
        [idInteresse:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 1
        [idProfissao:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 3
        [idPretencaoSalarial:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 4
        [experiencia:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 1
        [idTempoExperiencia:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 3
        [idExperienciaComprovada:InformacaoInteresseTO:private] => 2
    )

)
```

Comment: Seus atributos são privados, o que não permitirá você percorrer o objeto fora de seu próprio escopo para acessar cada atributo.

Comment: Explique melhor como seria um foreach para exibir esses dados.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34789/como-fazer-um-foreach-para-um-array-de-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach(EmpregadoTO as $valor){
    echo $valor->bairro;
    echo $valor->idStatus;
    .....
}
```

**PS: Não sei se vai mostrar os valores, pois como foi citado nos comentários de sua pergunta, você tem os atributos como privado.**