# Transformar array multidimensional em unidimensional

Tags: php

Como transformar este array em PHP:

```
 array:6 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "EF1A" => "00001"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [
        "EF2A" => "00001"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [
        "EF3A" => "00003"
      ]
      3 => array:1 [
        "EF4A" => "00005"
      ]
      4 => array:1 [
        "EF5A" => "00001"
      ]
      5 => array:1 [
        "EF6A" => "00001"
      ]
      6 => array:1 [
        "EF1A" => "00002"
      ]
    ]
```

Neste?

```
array:6 [          
        "EF1A" => "00001"         
        "EF2A" => "00001"          
        "EF3A" => "00003"          
        "EF4A" => "00005"          
        "EF5A" => "00001"          
        "EF6A" => "00001"
        "EF1A" => "00002"
    ]
```

Comment: Relacionado [Como fazer um foreach para um array de arrays?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34789/como-fazer-um-foreach-para-um-array-de-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

`$array` sendo o seu array bidimensional (original)

Para manter as chaves iguais originais de maneira a que as possamos trabalhar depois vamos ter de adotar uma solução mais 'manual' e colocar um prefixo por ex:

```
$array = array(
    array('fde432' => 1),
    array('fde1' => 7),
    array('fde3' => 2),
    array('fde1' => 6),
    array('fde3' => 3),
    array('fde2' => 5),
    array('fde1' => 4),
);

$merged = array();
$keys = array();
foreach($array as $key => $arr) {
    $innerKey = array_keys($arr)[0];
    if(!isset($keys[$innerKey])) {
        $keys[$innerKey] = 0;
    }
    else {
        $keys[$innerKey] += 1;
    }
    $prefix = $keys[$innerKey];
    $merged[$prefix. '_' .$innerKey] = $arr[$innerKey];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($merged), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
(
    [0_fde432] => 1
    [0_fde1] => 7
    [0_fde3] => 2
    [1_fde1] => 6
    [1_fde3] => 3
    [0_fde2] => 5
    [2_fde1] => 4
)
```

Comment: Dessa forma, as chaves dos arrays q são iguais são removidas. Preciso que fiquem rs

Comment: Isso é impossivel, não pode ter chaves iguais no mesmo layer do array @AmandaLima. Ora se fizer: `array('ola' => 1, 'ola' => 3);` só um deles é que permanece (o ultimo)

Comment: Entendi. Obrigada

Comment: @AmandaLima no entanto vou colocar uma solução para isso

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que existe um jeito mais simples, que seria usando a função `array_walk_recursive`. Considerando que os índices do `sub-array` não estão idênticos, podemos usar ele para criar um `array` unidimensional.

Veja:

```
$flatted = [];

array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use(&$flatted) {   
    $flatted[$key] = $value;     
});
```

A função `array_walk_recursive` percorre todos os valores do `array` recursivamente, através de um callback. Ela passa o primeiro argumento para função como sendo o valor, e o segundo, a chave.

Utilizamos a palavra chave `use` para utilizar uma variável externa dentro do escopo da nossa função anônima. Ao adicionar o operador `&` estamos fazendo uma atribuição por referência; ou seja, alterações feitas dentro da closure serão feitas na variável original `$flatted`.

Outro acréscimo que gostaria de fazer é, se você usar `array_merge`, como foi mencionado na outra questão, se você estiver usando o **PHP 5.6 >=**, você pode fazer assim:

```
 array_merge(... $array)
```

Isso simplifica o processo, evitando a chamada de `call_user_func_array`.

O sinal de reticências é nomeado de elipses em alguns casos. Trata-se das *funções variadicas*. Você pode ler mais sobre esse assunto aqui:

[Qual é o nome do operador ... usado no PHP 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87234/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-do-operador-usado-no-php-5-6)

[O que pode mudar com a implementação do variadic function?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52344/o-que-pode-mudar-com-a-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-variadic-function)

Exemplos no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6rzv45)

Comment: Acreditas que exista ou existe mesmo?