# Ordenar array conforme mais de uma condição

Tags: php

#### Cenário teste

Tenho o seguinte *array*, onde os registros são relacionados, ou seja, o chave de cada nível, é referente aos demais:

```
Array
(
    [regs] => Array
        (
            [c1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 1
                )

            [c2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 30
                    [3] => 20
                    [4] => 10
                )

            [c3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100
                    [1] => 200
                    [2] => 300
                    [3] => 200
                    [4] => 400
                )

            [c4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01:00
                    [1] => 02:00
                    [2] => 03:00
                    [3] => 04:00
                    [4] => 05:00
                )
        )
)
```

Array: `array ( 'regs' => array ( 'c1' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '2', 2 => '3', 3 => '2', 4 => '1', ), 'c2' => array ( 0 => '10', 1 => '20', 2 => '30', 3 => '20', 4 => '10', ), 'c3' => array ( 0 => '100', 1 => '200', 2 => '300', 3 => '200', 4 => '400', ), 'c4' => array ( 0 => '01:00', 1 => '02:00', 2 => '03:00', 3 => '04:00', 4 => '05:00', ), ), )`

---

#### Objetivo

Gostaria de "ordenar" o *array* mas mantendo o relacionamento dos valores.

Exemplo:

Ordenando por `c1, c2, c3`:

```
Array
(
    [regs] => Array
        (
            [c1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                )

            [c2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 20
                    [3] => 20
                    [4] => 30
                )

            [c3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100
                    [1] => 400
                    [2] => 200
                    [3] => 200
                    [4] => 300
                )

            [c4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01:00
                    [1] => 05:00
                    [2] => 02:00
                    [3] => 04:00
                    [4] => 03:00
                )

        )

)
```

#### Bônus

Quebrar e agrupar valores conforme condições.

Exemplo: unir todos valores que tiverem `c1, c2, c3` iguais:

```
Array
(
    [regs] => Array
        (
            [r1] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                    [c2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [c3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 100
                        )

                    [c4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 01:00
                        )

                )

            [r2] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                    [c2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20
                            [1] => 20
                        )

                    [c3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 200
                            [1] => 200
                        )

                    [c4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 02:00
                            [1] => 04:00
                        )

                )

            [r3] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                        )

                    [c2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30
                        )

                    [c3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 300
                        )

                    [c4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 03:00
                        )

                )

            [r4] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                    [c2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [c3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 400
                        )

                    [c4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 05:00
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

---

- Existem funções nativas que faça isso automaticamente?
- Como poderia fazer essas "ordenações"?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como fazer um foreach para um array de arrays?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34789/7210)

Comment: Você somente precisa fazer for dentro de for para ir ordenado pelos subníveis do seu array,  indo ordenando os níveis mais internos até ir para o último mais externo, fazendo ifs nas condições desejadas para a ordenação. Não é complexo mas pode ser meio confuso, pesquisa sobre ordenação de arrays em subníveis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ordenar, você precisará agrupar os valores utilizando a função `array_map`, fazer a ordenação com `usort` e depois voltar a estrutura original com `array_column`.

Por exemplo, você possui o seguinte array original:

```
array (
  'regs' => 
  array (
    'c1' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '2',
      2 => '3',
      3 => '2',
      4 => '1',
    ),
    'c2' => 
    array (
      0 => '10',
      1 => '20',
      2 => '30',
      3 => '20',
      4 => '10',
    ),
    'c3' => 
    array (
      0 => '100',
      1 => '200',
      2 => '300',
      3 => '200',
      4 => '400',
    ),
    'c4' => 
    array (
      0 => '01:00',
      1 => '02:00',
      2 => '03:00',
      3 => '04:00',
      4 => '05:00',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Você afirma que os valores de `c1`, `c2`, `c3` e `c4` estão relacionados entre si, então vamos agrupá-los em uma estrutura mais consistente com essa relação: vamos por todos os valores relacionados entre si no mesmo *array* utilizando a função `array_map`:

```
$agrupados = array_map(function($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4) {
    return compact('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');
}, $dados['regs']['c1'], $dados['regs']['c2'], $dados['regs']['c3'], $dados['regs']['c4']);
```

Uma forma simplificada de fazer o mesmo seria utilizar a função `array_values` e o operador `...`:

```
$agrupados = array_map(function($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4) {
    return compact('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');
}, ...array_values($dados['regs']));
```

O resultado seria:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '100',
    'c4' => '01:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '2',
    'c2' => '20',
    'c3' => '200',
    'c4' => '02:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '3',
    'c2' => '30',
    'c3' => '300',
    'c4' => '03:00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '2',
    'c2' => '20',
    'c3' => '200',
    'c4' => '04:00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '400',
    'c4' => '05:00',
  ),
)
```

Perceba que agora temos cada *array* com os valores associados entre si. Agora podemos ordenar conforme a prioridade `c1`, `c2` e `c3`:

```
usort($agrupados, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['c1'] > $b['c1']
        or $a['c2'] > $b['c2']
        or $a['c3'] > $b['c3'];
});
```

Isso ordenará, mas ainda permanecerá os *arrays* com os valores associados:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '100',
    'c4' => '01:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '400',
    'c4' => '05:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '2',
    'c2' => '20',
    'c3' => '200',
    'c4' => '02:00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '2',
    'c2' => '20',
    'c3' => '200',
    'c4' => '04:00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'c1' => '3',
    'c2' => '30',
    'c3' => '300',
    'c4' => '03:00',
  ),
)
```

Para voltar a estrutura atual, mas mantendo a ordenação, podemos utilizar a função `array_column`, que retornará um *array* com todos os valores daquela determinada coluna:

```
$ordenado = [
    'c1' => array_column($agrupados, 'c1'),
    'c2' => array_column($agrupados, 'c2'),
    'c3' => array_column($agrupados, 'c3'),
    'c4' => array_column($agrupados, 'c4')
];
```

Desta forma, o resultado será:

```
array (
  'c1' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '2',
    3 => '2',
    4 => '3',
  ),
  'c2' => 
  array (
    0 => '10',
    1 => '10',
    2 => '20',
    3 => '20',
    4 => '30',
  ),
  'c3' => 
  array (
    0 => '100',
    1 => '400',
    2 => '200',
    3 => '200',
    4 => '300',
  ),
  'c4' => 
  array (
    0 => '01:00',
    1 => '05:00',
    2 => '02:00',
    3 => '04:00',
    4 => '03:00',
  ),
)
```

Que é o *array* na estrutura original, mas com a ordenação desejada.

---

### Bônus

Para agrupar da forma que deseja, você pode usar a versão `$agrupados` da solução anterior percorrendo todos os valores do *array* e agrupando aqueles que possuem os mesmos valores de `c1`, `c2` e `c3`. Uma forma simples de gerar esse agrupamento é gerar uma chave em um *array* associativo que representa esses três valores, assim os itens que possuírem os mesmos valores possuirão as mesmas chaves.

```
$resultado = [];

foreach($agrupados as $item) {
    // Gera uma chave única considerando os três valores
    $chave = "{$item['c1']}, {$item['c2']}, {$item['c3']}";

    // Se não existir, adiciona; caso contrário agrupa os valores
    if (!array_key_exists($chave, $resultado)) {
        $resultado[$chave] = $item;
    } else {
        foreach (array_keys($item) as $k) {
            if (!is_array($resultado[$chave][$k])) {
                $resultado[$chave][$k] = [$resultado[$chave][$k]];
            }

            $resultado[$chave][$k][] = $item[$k];
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado será:

```
array (
  '1, 10, 100' => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '100',
    'c4' => '01:00',
  ),
  '1, 10, 400' => 
  array (
    'c1' => '1',
    'c2' => '10',
    'c3' => '400',
    'c4' => '05:00',
  ),
  '2, 20, 200' => 
  array (
    'c1' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
      1 => '2',
    ),
    'c2' => 
    array (
      0 => '20',
      1 => '20',
    ),
    'c3' => 
    array (
      0 => '200',
      1 => '200',
    ),
    'c4' => 
    array (
      0 => '02:00',
      1 => '04:00',
    ),
  ),
  '3, 30, 300' => 
  array (
    'c1' => '3',
    'c2' => '30',
    'c3' => '300',
    'c4' => '03:00',
  ),
)
```

Perceba que somente os valores em `r2`, que possuem `c1`, `c2` e `c3` iguais a 2, 20 e 200, respectivamente, que ficaram agrupados. A partir disso basta renomear as chaves do *array* final para `r1`, `r2`, etc conforme desejado.